# Groovy MockFor demand instance method. return this

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, delegates, mocking, this

I'm using a Groovy MockFor class to test smth like this.

I have an AClass with `public AClass aMethod()`, that must return some instance of AClass. (same, or not, it's didn't matter.) In my mock class I want to return exactly same proxy instance, for correct and easy verify check.

But can't find a way to do this.

```
MockFor mock = new MockFor(AClass)
mock.demand.aMethod { ... ->
log.info("aMethod was called!")
    // Here I want to return same mock proxy instance!
    return //<this???>
}

def instance = mock.proxyDelegateInstance()
instance = instance.aMethod(...) // Call to demanded method. In AClass aMethod returns AClass instance!

// so, I will be able to demand aMethod multiple times, and then ask
mock.verify(instance) // Will check, how many times method was called for same instance.
```

I think, I can set closure delegate, and then demand it, but it didn't look like a good solution.

So, I ask for an advise.

Comment: I assume you can't just `return mock.proxyDelegateInstance()`?

Comment: @tim_yates  But it will create new instance, and verify method will become useless.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
def mock = new MockFor( AClass )
def instance

mock.demand.aMethod { a ->
    println "Mocked $a"
    instance
}

instance = mock.proxyDelegateInstance()
instance = instance.aMethod( 'woo' )
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but no. There is two way's to call demanded method. Wrap some code with `mock.use` or create an instance, and then call method directly. In such case, demanded methods will be called to. And, in standard OOP semantics, I will be able to access current instance with this keyword. I'v asked about a way to imitate such behaviour.

Comment: @Seagull Ok, how about that?

Comment: In such case instance is captured from outer contexts, so, it makes method demanding scope dependant. I'll think, I'm fixed issue. Will post extended message later, after testing.